Horror movie with mother and daughter and an evil hitchhiker
I remember seeing the trailer when I was little (I think it was 5 or 6 years ago) but I can't remember the name. It was in English.
A mother and her daughter(?) were driving along a lonely road at night at winter time(?). They picked up a hitchhiker and he pulled out a stick with dead rats(?) on it and he began to eat them. The mom pulled over and told him to get out. Shortly afterward (while they were continuing their drive) their car broke down. The mom said she was gonna get help and told her daughter to stay in the car.
When people who were driving by came to assist them, I'm thinking the guy caught up and killed them.

Welcome to M&TV. "when I was little" When was that, approximately? Was it in English?

@Walt i think it was 5 or 6 years ago. Yes it was English

You're describing the trailer of Penny Dreadful from 2006, only it's not a mother and daughter.

Penny (Rachel Miner), a young woman traumatized by a childhood auto accident that killed her parents, accompanies her therapist Orianna (Mimi Rogers) on a road trip to a mountain community as part of her therapy to overcome her fear of cars. On the way, Orianna hits, but does not seriously injure, a hitchhiker, who she then offers a ride. The hitchhiker is silent during the ride, except to point out his destination.

It doesn't go well from there... You can see the scene with the hitchhiker eating a skewer of raw meat in the trailer around the 1 minute mark:




this is the movie!! thank you so much :D
been looking everywhere for this!

@RomanAtwoodFan No problem, but don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.
